# How to add a yes/no response in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a script that I would like to add a yes/no response to before executing each profile delete/removal. This script is for deleting old profile on remote workstations.  It allows me to enter the workstation I want to remote to and calls for the number of days since last login of profiles. For example if I input 60 days since last logged in all profiles that have not login in the past 60 day will be deleted.  I would like the option to chose yes or no to before a profile is deleted.  The script otherwise works fine. This is the script. Any Help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```
@ECHO OFF
echo ####################################################
echo #                                                 #
echo #   Welcome to the User Profile Deletion tool,   #
echo #   this tool is to only be used on common use   #
echo #       Computers, to clear old profiles       #
echo #                                                 #
echo #   you will be prompted for approving offical   #
echo #   This is the requestor of the profile wipe!   #
echo #   and the number of days since last logon,   #
echo #         you wish to start the clean at.       # 
echo #                                                 #
echo ####################################################
echo.
REM set /p approving=approving offical that requested the wipe:
set /p days2=How many days to keep? 
echo.
set UsersPath=%systemdrive%\Users\
DEL /F /Q /A:H %UsersPath%\desktop.ini 2>nul>nul
forfiles /p %UsersPath% /m * /d -%days2% /c "cmd /c echo @file">%TEMP%\users.temp
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=" %%P IN (%TEMP%\users.temp) DO CALL:UserDeleteJoin %%P
set userdelete=%userdelete:"=%
set userdelete=%userdelete:~0,-1%
GOTO:USERPRESERVE

:UserDeleteJoin
if UserDeleteJoin_Skip=="" (set userdelete=%1 & set UserDeleteJoin_Skip=1) ELSE (set userdelete=%1,%userdelete%)
goto:eof

:USERPRESERVE
set userpreserve="All Users,Default,Default User,Public,AnyOtherUserName"

FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('reg query "hklm\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\profilelist"^|find /i "s-1-5-21"') DO CALL :REGCHECK "%%a"
GOTO VERIFY

:REGCHECK
set SPACECHECK=
FOR /f "tokens=3,4" %%b in ('reg query %1 /v ProfileImagePath') DO SET USERREGPATH=%%b %%c
FOR /f "tokens=2" %%d in ('echo %USERREGPATH%') DO SET SPACECHECK=%%d
IF ["%SPACECHECK%"]==[""] GOTO REGCHECK2
GOTO USERCHECK

:REGCHECK2
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('reg query %1 /v ProfileImagePath') DO SET USERREGPATH=%%g
GOTO USERCHECK

:USERCHECK
FOR /f "tokens=3 delims=\" %%e in ('echo %USERREGPATH%') DO SET USERREG=%%e
FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%f IN ('echo %USERREG%') DO SET USERREGPARSE=%%f
ECHO %USERPRESERVE%|find /I "%USERREGPARSE%" > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL=1 GOTO DELETECHECK
IF ERRORLEVEL=0 GOTO SKIP

:DELETECHECK
FOR /f "tokens=3 delims=\" %%e in ('echo %USERREGPATH%') DO SET USERREG=%%e
FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%f IN ('echo %USERREG%') DO SET USERREGPARSE=%%f
ECHO %userdelete%|find /I "%USERREGPARSE%" > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL=1 GOTO SKIP
IF ERRORLEVEL=0 GOTO CLean
GOTO:EOF

:SKIP
ECHO Skipping user clean for %USERREG%
GOTO :EOF

:CLEAN
set /a profiles=%profiles%+1
ECHO Cleaning user profile for %USERREG%
rmdir /s "C:\Users\%USERREG%" /s /q > NUL
ECHO Cleaning user registry for %USERREG%
reg delete %1 /f
IF EXIST "C:\Users\%USERREG%" GOTO RETRYCLEAN1
GOTO :EOF

:RETRYCLEAN1
ECHO Retrying clean of user profile %USERREG%
rmdir /s "C:\Users\%USERREG%" /s /q > NUL
IF EXIST "C:\Users\%USERREG%" GOTO RETRYCLEAN2
GOTO :EOF

:RETRYCLEAN2
ECHO Retrying clean of user profile %USERREG%
rmdir "C:\Users\%USERREG%" /s /q > NUL
GOTO :EOF

:VERIFY
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%g IN ('reg query "hklm\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\profilelist"^|find /i "s-1-5-21"') DO CALL :REGCHECKV "%%g"
GOTO REPORT

:REGCHECKV
set SPACECHECKV=
FOR /f "tokens=3,4" %%h in ('reg query %1 /v ProfileImagePath') DO SET USERREGPATHV=%%h %%i
FOR /f "tokens=2" %%j in ('echo %USERREGPATHV%') DO SET SPACECHECKV=%%j
IF ["%SPACECHECKV%"]==[""] GOTO REGCHECKV2
GOTO USERCHECKV

:REGCHECKV2
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%k in ('reg query %1 /v ProfileImagePath') DO SET USERREGPATHV=%%k
GOTO USERCHECKV

:USERCHECKV
FOR /f "tokens=3 delims=\" %%l in ('echo %USERREGPATHV%') DO SET USERREGV=%%l
FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%m IN ('echo %USERREGV%') DO SET USERREGPARSEV=%%m
ECHO %USERPRESERVE%|find /I "%USERREGPARSEV%" > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL=1 GOTO VERIFYERROR
IF ERRORLEVEL=0 GOTO :EOF

:VERIFYERROR
SET USERERROR=YES
GOTO :EOF

:REPORT
IF [%USERERROR%]==[YES] (
        set RESULT=FAILURE
)     ELSE (
        set RESULT=SUCCESS
)

echo Total Profiles Cleaned is %profiles%
Pause
:EXIT
exit

:EOF
```

Comment: You can either use the `SET`  command with the `/P` option or the `CHOICE` command.  Open up a command prompt and type: `set /?` and `choice /?` to read the help for both commands.

Comment: The question I guess is where would I put it?

Comment: I would think you would be the one to know that. You wrote the code.  I am not going to read all that code and decide where it has to go.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]! Read also the [tour] and learn [ask] here!

Comment: You're code would only remove a directory tree, not registry references etc. I'd suggest you instead use [Delprof2](https://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/). As a side note, using `powershell.exe` would be better, where this,`GWMI Win32_UserProfile -F "Loaded=False And Special=False And LocalPath Like '%:%'"|Select LocalPath,@{N="LastUsed";E={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastUseTime)}}|?{$_.LastUseTime -LT $(Get-Date).AddMonths(-1)}`, should show you unused local profiles with last used dates beyond `1` month, _replacable with `.AddDays(-10)` for beyond `10` days_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert these 3 lines after the line `:CLEAN` at line 66.

```
set "reply=y"
set /p "reply=Clean user profile for %USERREG%? [y|n]: "
if /i not "%reply%" == "y" goto :eof
```

If you type `y` or just press enter which implies `y`, it continues the clean, else other input implies `n` which goes to end of file.

Comment: Joe L, To expand upon the other option provided by @Squashman in his comment, you could alternatively use `Choice /M "Clean user profile for %USERREG%"` followed by `If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo :EOF`.